# I wrote a way to add comments, but it didn't run

Tags: django, python-3.x

My idea is to create a model of articles and comments. When users initiate comments, they can directly create data, but adding comments in the actual operation does not respond.

```py
#views.py
def details(request, article_id):
    detail = LifeArticle.objects.get(id=article_id)
    comment = LifeComment.objects.get(article=detail)
    return render(request, 'lifedetail.html', locals())

def addcomment(request, article_id):
    article = LifeArticle.objects.get(id=article_id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        content = request.POST['content']
        r = LifeComment.create(article=article, user=request.user, content=content)
        msg = '添加成功'
        return render(request, 'lifedetail.html', locals())
    else:
        return render(request, 'lifedetail.html',)

#urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^life/(?P<article_id>\d+)/', views.details),
    url(r'^article/life/(?P<article_id>\d+)/addcoment/', views.addcomment)
]

#lifedetail.html
{% if detail %}
<div id='article'>
<form action="/article/life/{{detail.id}}/addcoment/" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ detail.title }}</td>
        <td>{{ detail.content }}</td>
        <td>{{ detail.user }}</td>
    </tr>
</div>
<div id="comment">
{% if comment %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ comment.content }}</td>
        <td>{{ comment.user }}</td>
    </tr>
</div>
{% else %}
<p>暂无评论</p>
{% endif %}
<input type="text" name="content">
<input type="submit" value="提交">
</form>
{% else %}
<p>暂无文章</p>
{% endif %}
{{msg}}
</div>
```

These are my code. Now I can't find the reason. I'm also looking at Django2.2's documentation to find the problem

Comment: You might wanna explain the issue you are having. any error messages etc.

Comment: yes,but I didn't find the reason

Comment: I've done an anchor operation in the method so that the program prints the anchor when it executes the method, but I didn't actually reference the method when I added a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in this line:

```
r = LifeComment.create(article=article, user=request.user, content=content)
```

I think you should use `objects` here:

```
r = LifeComment.objects.create(article=article, user=request.user, content=content)
```

Also, you need to send `detail` information from context:

```
def addcomment(request, article_id):
    article = LifeArticle.objects.get(id=article_id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        # rest of the code
    else:
        return render(request, 'lifedetail.html', context={'detail':article})
```

Comment: Method not running, comment not added successfully

Comment: thx,This answer solved my problem.I want to know why I do this?